# Dropzone.js already attached

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, dropzone.js

I've implemented dropzone in to my project all is working great. except the browser decides to throw an error whenever the page is request for clarity I have trimmed the view down as its quite long, but the below HTML currently lives inside a form (not sure if that would cause an issue anyway) I only have the one reference to dropzone which is shown here, the dropzone.js is included inside the bundle config again only one occurrence.

Error :  if(this.element.dropzone)throw new Error("Dropzone already attached.")

This is my view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 dropzone" id="UploadImage">
         <input type="file" id="id-input-file-2" />
     </div>
</div>
```

This is how I create dropzone

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("div#UploadImage").dropzone({ url: '@Url.Action("SaveUploadedFile", "Person")' });
 });
```

and my controller which is as follows

```
 public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile()
    {
        bool success = true;

        string fName = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            foreach (var file in Request.Files.Cast<string>().Select(fileName => Request.Files[fileName]).Where(file => file != null))
            {
                fName = file.FileName;

                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                   // will write the rest of the code here
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
        }

        return Json(success ? new { Message = fName } : new { Message = "Error in saving file" });
    }
```

now I'm able to retrieve the images within the controller just uncertain on where in the code the dropzone is being initialized again which is resulting in the above error.

***UPDATE***

After trying Daves suggestion my jquery now looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = false;

        $("div#UploadImage").dropzone({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveUploadedFile", "Person")',
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            removedfile: function (file) {
                var name = file.name;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUploadedFile", "Person")',
                    data: "id=" + name,
                    dataType: 'html'
                });
                var ref;
                return (ref = file.previewElement) != null ? ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
            },
            maxFilesize: 2,
            maxFiles: 12,

        });
});
```

But yet I still get the error.

Answer (score 3):

Try from [Reference here](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ)

1. Turn off autoDiscover globally like this: Dropzone.autoDiscover =
   false;,  or
2. Turn off autoDiscover of specific elements like this:
       Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = false;

Comment: I have tried this and updated my question with the new Jquery yet I still get the error?!?! I have put what you suggested above my implementation of Dropzone

Answer (score 2):

Remove "dropzone" from the class attribute on the UploadImage element and the error will go away. I had the same issue and that fixed it.

I think you're giving the plugin mixed messages by setting autoDiscover to false and also setting the class of an element to "dropzone."

Answer (score 1):

This is the only solution that worked for me.

What I ended up doing is renaming the css class to "dropzone1", and then renamed all of the instances of "dropzone" to "dropzone1" in the basic.cs and dropzone.cs files.  That way I kept all of the CSS styling.

Once I did that, it worked like a charm.